# Leer dispositivo usb y enviar datos a otro dispositivo

Tags: nodejs

Tengo un cable USB macho a macho y para experimentar un poco tengo la idea de usar el PC para interceptar los datos que envía un control de PS4 a la consola.

Quiero que el flujo sea el siguiente:

```
Control---------->PC------------->PS4.
```

Es decir que pase primero por el PC y sea este quien envía los datos a la consola.

Actualmente estoy obteniendo los datos del Control con la librería [node-hid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-hid) de la siguiente forma:

```
device.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // enviar datos a la consola
});
```

¿Es posible tomar esos datos y enviarlos a travez de otro puerto USB?

Creo que necesito agregar otra librería para lo que quiero pero estoy un poco perdido.

Comment: Si no estoy mal, deberías tener dos cables de esos, uno desde el control al pc y el otro del pc al puerto del control del ps4, una vez tengas eso es abrir ambos dispositivos con ayuda de hid, y cuando recibas los datos de uno, los envias al otro por medio de la funcion `.write()`

Comment: si tengo los 2 cables... pero el hid no detecta la consola, supongo que  el puerto de la consola es solo para recibir datos.